# How to get Tango field of view in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, google-project-tango, fieldofview

currently I attached the TangoARScreen script to the Tango camera prefab in Unity, is it possible to retrieve the field of view value in Unity via C# script?

In addition, is it possible to use the front facing camera in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is possible ddddddddaxing.

Get ready, here is what you need to do:

**Let's take a look at retrieving intrinsic parameters from the C API for a general overview of the underpinning logic. The steps are:**

1. Create a **TangoCameraIntrinsics** struct.
2. Call the `TangoService_getCameraIntrinsics` function. Pass it the ID for the camera and the address of the struct.

For example, to get the color camera intrinsics:

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics ccIntrinsics;
TangoService_getCameraIntrinsics(TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, &ccIntrinsics);
```

*The function populates the struct with intrinsic information.*

For C# specifically to use in **Unity** this should look something like this:

1. Create a **TangoCameraIntrinsics** struct object.
2. Call the `GetIntrinsics` method of the `Tango.VideoOverlayProvider` class.

*The method populates the struct with intrinsic information.*

**Now you can look at using the Intrinsics to calculate FOV from the Focal length.**

All the parameters you need to calculate FOV can be retrieved from the API.

/// Parameter /// Description

/// width /// The width of the image on the image sensor in pixels.

/// height /// The height of the image on the image sensor in pixels.

/// fx /// Focal length, x axis, in pixels.

/// fy /// Focal length, y axis, in pixels.

*Note that in most systems, fx = fy.*

**For Example, lets look at this in C:**

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics ccIntrinsics;
TangoService_getCameraIntrinsics(TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR, &ccIntrinsics);
```

When you examine the `ccIntrinsics` struct, you should something like the following data:

```
ccIntrinsics.height=720;
ccIntrinsics.fy=1042.0;
```

Therefore:

```
 Vertical FOV = 2*atan(0.5*720.0/1042.0) = 2*19.0549 deg = 38.1098 deg
```

*The equations for the horizontal and vertical fields of view are:*

/// Horizontal FOV = 2 * atan(0.5 * width / Fx)

/// Vertical FOV = 2 * atan(0.5 * height / Fy)

*If your rendering engine only supports one FOV value, refer to its documentation to know which FOV to use. If you require the diagonal field of view, the equation is:*

/// Diagonal FOV = 2 * arctan(sqrt((width/2Fx)^2 + (height/2Fy)^2))

*The lenses in cameras are not perfect and add some amount of distortion. For most use cases the effect is small enough to ignore; however, when a Tango device is calibrated, it examines and stores distortion information and these values are available in the `TangoCameraIntrinsics` struct (C and Unity).*

*If you are using the motion tracking camera (sometimes called the **"fisheye" lens**), then the ["FOV" distortion model](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4538852/?reload=true) is used and the `TangoCameraIntrinsics` struct/object will contain the calibration type `TANGO_CALIBRATION_EQUIDISTANT`.*

*If you are using the color camera, then the [polynomial distortion model](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1087109/) is used and the `TangoCameraIntrinsics` struct/object will contain the calibration type `TANGO_CALIBRATION_POLYNOMIAL_3_PARAMETERS`.*

For some further depth, have a look at the VideoOverlayProvider.cs Script on Git [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Core/Scripts/TangoWrappers/VideoOverlayProvider.cs)

SECOND QUESTION-

Accessing the front camera will require you to discard the Tango functionality and disconnect from the `TangoCore` service. You can re-enable this mid application by forcing the `TangoUx` package and relocalizing, however you will have lost motion tracking and unless your application is using area learning, this might disorient the end user. 
If I recall correctly, you can select this via a dropdown list in the Inspector on the `TangoMultiCamera` Prefab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However I'm not very sure about the calculation in C#, for example the vertical FOV, the atan would return a value between -pi/2 to pi/2, while the field of view is 0 to pi, should the vertical FOV add pi/2 to be mapped in the correct range?